# CRM 4: Export the product catalog

Tags: dynamics-crm, product

I'm trying to move our product catalog from one CRM 4 install to another, is there a way this can be done, without backing up and restoring the CRM 4 database from the old install?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the bulk data export tool for CRM4 to export the data you are looking for then import it back into your other installation.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crm/archive/2008/04/30/crm-4-0-bulk-data-export-tool.aspx